# yield item issue in errback or in case of 302 Request

Tags: python, scrapy

I have an issue using scrapy

```
yield Request(a_url[0],
                    meta={'item': aitem}, dont_filter=True,
                    callback=self.redeem_url, errback=self.error_page)


    def redeem_url(self, response):
       item = response.request.meta['item']
       item['Click_to_Redeem_URL'] = response.url
       yield item
```

`aitem` is populated before doing `a_url[0]` request. Sometimes I get 302, 404, 301 status from `Request` so what I want is if I can't get 200 response from `a_url[0]` request item should yield I didn't found any way because when I got 302 scrapy retry on this request and not go to `error_page` errback, and if in 404 it goes to `error_page` what would be the way to yield item over there because what I know in errback I can't get response object but a failure object that not contains item in meta.

thanks in advance

Comment: Very unclear question. Could you please explain what it is about?

Comment: @Secator its very much clear its about scrapy, a python library, and the issue is how to deal an item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
yield Request(a_url[0],
                meta={'item': aitem, 'dont_retry':1}, dont_filter=True,
                callback=self.redeem_url, 
                errback=lambda x:self.error_page(x,aitem))


def redeem_url(self, response):
   item = response.request.meta['item']
   item['Click_to_Redeem_URL'] = response.url
   yield item
```

The dont_retry should stop the scrapy retry:

http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.retry

The lambda should allow the aitem to get passed to your error callback.

Comment: thanks for this solution but, what if we stop dont_retry it would not go in an error_page, so how can we yield that item ?

Comment: My understanding is that if you turn off retry, then the response will be passed to the callback instead.  Is this not happening for you?